How to tell if data belongs to a probability distirbution?
In school, here is the general framework we learned that relates random data to a probability distribution (i.e. Maximum Likelihood Estimation):
$$x_1, x_2, ..., x_n \text{ (observed data)}$$
$$p(x; \theta_1, ..., \theta_m) \text{ (probability distribution with parameters }\theta_1, ..., \theta_m)$$
$$L(\theta_1, ..., \theta_m; x_1, ..., x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i; \theta_1, ..., \theta_m)$$
$$\ell(\theta_1, ..., \theta_m; x_1, ..., x_n) = \log L(\theta_1, ..., \theta_m; x_1, ..., x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log p(x_i; \theta_1, ..., \theta_m)$$
$$\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \theta_j} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j} \log p(x_i; \theta_1, ..., \theta_m) \quad \text{for } j = 1, ..., m$$
$$\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \theta_j} = 0 \quad \text{for } j = 1, ..., m$$
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \theta_1} = 0 \\
\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \theta_2} = 0 \\
\vdots \\
\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \theta_m} = 0
\end{cases}$$
$$\hat{\theta}_1, \hat{\theta}_2, ..., \hat{\theta}_m$$
As I understand, this describes the joint probability of a the observed data belonging to a pre-determined probability distribution function.
I always wondered about the following:
Suppose I have some observed data and believe the data came from a Normal Distribution. As I understand - in general, regardless of the Normal Distribution (i.e. regardless of the value of mean, sigma): They should all have the same cumulative probabilities:
For a continuous random variable X with probability density function f(x), the cumulative distribution function (CDF) F(x) is defined as:
$$F(x) = P(X \leq x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t) dt$$
As an example for the Normal Distribution:
$$F_X(x; \mu, \sigma) = F_Z\left(\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}\right)$$
Where:

$F_X(x; \mu, \sigma)$ is the CDF of a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$
$F_Z(z)$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution (mean 0, standard deviation 1)
$z = \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}$ is the standardized value

I think this relationship should hold for any $\mu$ and $\sigma$, demonstrating that the underlying shape of the CDF remains invariant, just shifted and scaled. More generally, for any distribution, I think  we can express this invariance property as:
$$F_X(x; \theta_1, \theta_2, ..., \theta_n) = F_S(h(x; \theta_1, \theta_2, ..., \theta_n))$$
Where:

$F_X(x; \theta_1, \theta_2, ..., \theta_n)$ is the CDF of the distribution with parameters $\theta_1, \theta_2, ..., \theta_n$
$F_S(s)$ is the CDF of a standardized version of the distribution
$h(x; \theta_1, \theta_2, ..., \theta_n)$ is a standardization function

Based on these facts:
Suppose I have some random observed data and I believe its from a Normal Distribution. I can use MLE to estimate the parameters of this distribution. But could I also see if the empirical CDF of the observed data matches the theoretical CDF of a generic Normal Distribution?
E.g.

Suppose in my random data, 5% of the data is less than some constant $c_1$
In a generic Normal Distribution, 5% of the data is less than some constant $c'_1$
Suppose in my random data, 10% of the data is less than some constant $c_2$
In a generic Normal Distribution, 10% of the data is less than some constant $c'_2$
etc.

In this case, if all $c_i$ and $c'_i$ are roughly equal, we could conclude that the random observed data indeed belongs to the hypothesized PDF?
To conclude : MLE tells the likelihood of the data coming from a specific probability distribution with specific parameter values ... an EDF/CDF comparison seems like it would provide (in essence) the same information? Does doing this EDF/CDF comparison provide any added value compared to simply doing MLE? (my guess is no...)

Probably you are looking for Goodness of Fit tests. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit
